# На каком языке программирования стоит писать веб-приложение/веб-сайт в 2021 году?

Tags: java, python, веб-программирование

Собираюсь написать веб-сайт, так как я начинал программировать на Java, начал на Java, используя Spring Boot. Но задумался, не возникнет ли трудностей в поддержке сайта в будущем, поиске разработчиков? Знаю, еще есть Python, со своим Django, на нем тоже чуть-чуть практиковался. На каком начать разрабатывать веб-сайт в 2021 году?

P.s. Но опыта программирования, у меня, на Java намного больше.

Comment: На тех же языках, что и в 2020 и в 2019. Глобально и резко ничего не поменялось.

Answer (score 2):

Некорректный вопрос. Пишите на чем Вам удобно. Будь то Java (Spring), C# (ASP.NET), Python (Django). Ориентируйтесь на свое желание, навыки (если ищете работу, то можете ориентироваться на вакансии, которые Вас интересуют, на технологии, которые чаще требуются в стеке компании работодателя)

Answer (score 0):

На ruby можно. А так на чем угодно, хоть на ассемблере, это ваш выбор.